# Does Laravel Support Timeout Option for Queue Workers?

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, laravel-5, queue

I know Laravel has a `--timeout` option for their `php artisan queue:listen` command, however I would like to use `queue:work` instead to save some CPU usage.  As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to set the timeout option with the queue worker.  Will it time out if my job takes more than the 60 second default, or does the timeout just apply to `queue:listen`?

I just want to make sure my jobs have enough time to run since I'm doing things like running reports in the background, and some take more than 60 seconds to generate due to the size of the dataset.  It seems like they're running ok, I just want some clarification as to how that works so that I can make sure I won't run into issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the --timeout is an artificial timeout in Symphony's Process class.

If you're using supervisord, it shouldn't time out, but you might want to look at your PHP max_execution_time.